# Error with macports while installing nodejs

Tags: macports

I want to install nodes using macports.

But It doesn't work at all:

```
$ sudo port install nodejs
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for nodejs
--->  Staging nodejs into destroot
Error: org.macports.destroot for port nodejs returned: xinstall: Cannot stat: out/Release/node, No such file or directory
Please see the log file for port nodejs for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_nodejs/nodejs/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port nodejs failed
$
```

I tried the following command, but still not working:

```
$ sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I manage to solve by running

```
$ sudo xcodebuild -license
```

and then building from scratch by cleaning the building files by doing

```
$ sudo port clean nodejs; sudo port install nodejs
```